# ElasticSearch _search API - why doesn't it return version by default?

Tags: elasticsearch

When using the `_search` API if you want the version number of every record to be returned you need to specify that directly.  [source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-version.html)

```
GET /_search
{
    "version": true,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Why is this?  Is there a performance hit for returning the version with every record?

Comment: What is the response you get?

Comment: Better to post this question on the ES forums.  It is probably omitted, because its a value that most consumers/consuming apps don't care about.